# Jedox Integrator RScript Transform: Failed to retrieve data

Tags: r, rjava, rscript, integrator, jedox

Currently I'm working with Jedox and try to use the RScript Transform component.

The installation of R itself on the server was a little bit tricky, but after several attempts it finally worked. 
For the installation helpful were the infos on this blog: [jedoxtools.wordpress.com](https://jedoxtools.wordpress.com/2015/04/21/jedox-etl-integration-of-r-and-r-studio/)

The key challenge though was to enter the correct directory path in the 'Path' (C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64) and in the 'R_Home' (C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1) variables.

But now where the 'hard part' should already be done I simply can't get the transform component running.
Based on the example Rscript in this [presentation](http://www.business-analytics-day.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/07_OSBI_Jedox_R.pdf) everytime I try simple scripts, I got the following error message:

> Failed to retrieve data from source [my RScript components name] : null

The script I run is as simple as this:

```
data <- my_datasource
Result <- data
```

There is data in the source and if I do the test locally in RStudio it works perfectly fine.

Anyone here with R experiences in Jedox?

Comment: do you have the correct path set? possibly with some relative path way. the path on your local machine will be surely different...

Comment: my local test was just to verify the syntax and behaviour of R. No further correlation to the R installation on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few attempts later I found the solution myself and it's of course super easy, u just have to know about it.

In the [Jedox documentation](https://knowledgebase.jedox.com/6_0/knowledgebase/transform-rscript/) the given example shows a script which indicates the returned result set is called 'result'.
Instead you can return any object, all you have to do is to **name the result set in an extra field** which is above the script-box.
The working script (input=output) is shown here:

[rscript solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIw8m.png)